# plotting geom_text at individual positions in each facet of facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this dataset

```
df <- data.frame(groups=factor(c(rep("A",6), rep("B",6), rep("C",6))),
                 types=factor(c(rep(c(rep("Z",2), rep("Y",2), rep("X",2)),3))),
                 values=c(10,11,1,2,0.1, 0.2, 12,13, 2,2.5, 0.2, 0.01, 
                          12,14, 2,3,0.1,0.2))
library(ggplot2)
px <- ggplot(df, aes(groups, values)) + facet_wrap(~types, scale="free") + geom_point()
px
```

i conducted post-hoc analysis (values~groups for each level of types) and created a dataset, which contains significance groups (as letters: a, b, c and so on):

```
df.text <- data.frame(groups=factor(c(rep("A",3), rep("B",3), rep("C",3))),
                      label=rep("a", 9))
```

i proceeded to plot the labels on `px`:

```
px + geom_text(data=df.text, aes(x=groups, y=0.1, label=label), size=4, col="red", stat="identity") +theme_bw()
```

which doesnt look great.

My problem is to define a `aes(y)` in `geom_text`, which plots the labels at at a fixed position (e.g. above the x-axis or on top of the panel), without shifting the limits of the y axis too much. With previous datasets, the y-values were quite homogeneous among groups, so i could get away with a very low y-value. This time however the range of y is quite high, so its not easily getting done.

So, the question is how to plot the labels inside df.text at a fixed position in `facet_wrap`, while keeping `scale="free"`. Best would be above the top panel.border.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define a new variable `height` which determines the height to plot the labels:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(types) %>% 
  mutate(height = max(values) + .3 * sd(values)) %>% 
  left_join(df.text, by = "groups") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(groups, values)) + 
  facet_wrap(~types, scale = "free") + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(aes(x = groups, y = height, label = label), size = 4, col = "red", stat = "identity") +
  theme_bw()
```

Here I used the max value plus .3 times the standard deviation but you could change that to whatever you wanted obviously. Not sure how to get the labels on top of the panel strips though.

Comment: thank you. how do i have to adjust the code if label is not a constant string?

Comment: You can use `dplyr::left_join()` to join your lookup table, I edited my answer to reflect this.